# Generating b/w bitmaps from a binary sequence

Tags: image-processing, image, binary

I would like to make a bitmap that visually represents a binary sequence, something like this:

[image: bitmap]

Where for example the 1's become a black pixel and the 0's a white one. I have never done something similar on Mathematica, so I need some guidance for this. Any idea appreciated. Please note that I'm a beginner at this programming language, so keep it easy please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = RandomInteger[1, {300, 300}];

Image[data]
```

[image]

or

```
Graphics[Raster[data]]
```

[image]

You can also try:

```
ArrayPlot[data]
RandomImage[BernoulliDistribution[1/2], {300, 300}]
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ListDensityPlot[Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}], {100}, {100}],
       InterpolationOrder -> 0,
       ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why but this one kept running for a while and then crashed my poor laptop. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Mine rendered in 0.5341 seconds using v. 10.0.0 on a Mac Pro.